# "Variable" is undefined JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Estoy **llamando unos datos de una base de datos de Firebase**, el código:

```
db.collection("citas_registradas").where("fecha", "==", fecha).where("hora", "==", hora)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

                var fechaValidacion = fecha;
                var horaValidacion = hora;

            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        });
```

Y mis **validaciones**:

```
if (fecha == fechaValidacion && hora == horaValidacion) {
        Swal.fire("Oops!", "La cita ya está llena, por favor, busque una hora libre y asigne la cita.", "error");
} 
else if (fecha != fechaValidacion && hora != horaValidacion || fecha == fechaValidacion && hora != horaValidacion) {
Swal.fire("¡Genial!", "La cita está disponible.", "success");
}
```

Pero a la hora de probar mi app, y meter una fecha y hora que ya está registrada, me indica el siguiente error:

> "fechaValidacion" is undefined

¿Hay alguna forma de enviar esas variables que se usan sólo dentro del db.collection a una **variable "global"** para que **almacene el dato**, o una **forma de definirla**? , desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu variable está `undefined` porque está dentro de un *local scope* que en este caso sería el `then` si quieres acceder a esa variable desde un scope global no podrás porque solo está disponible dentro de ese scope y de los scope más anidados, no sé si logro explicarme.
Mete tu condicional dentro del `then` y ya está

```
//CODIGO PARA LLAMAR FECHA Y HORA DE LA BASE DE DATOS
db.collection("citas_registradas").where("fecha", "==", fecha).where("hora", "==", hora)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        var fechaV;
        var horaV;
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

            fechaV = fecha;
            horaV = hora;

        });

        //validacion si la fecha ingresada es igual a la fecha que retorna la base de datos y la hora es igual a la hora
        //que retorna la base de datos, es por que la cita está llena.
        if (fecha == fechaV && hora == horaV) {
            Swal.fire("Oops!", "La cita ya está llena, por favor, busque una hora libre y asigne la cita.", "error");

            //si la fecha es diferente a la que retorna la base de datos y la hora igual, o la fecha es igual a la de la base
            //de datos pero la hora es diferente, registra la cita.
        } else if (fecha != fechaV && hora != horaV || fecha == fechaV && hora != horaV) {
Swal.fire("¡Genial!", "La cita está libre.", "success");
```

}

Comment: He probado tu código amigo, y tampoco funciona, el return no funciona ya que necesito retornar ambas:  "fechaValidacion" y "horaValidacion" , pero ninguna de las dos opciones funciona bro...

Referencia de error en consola: Uncaught ReferenceError: fechaValidacion is not defined

Comment: pero si vas a probar el código que puse, la comparacion ya no tiene que se con fechaValidación, sino con varGlobal, Con respecto a tu problema de retornar ámbas, lo puede hacerlo retornando como un objeto

Comment: exacto, he probado las validaciones con varGlobal, pero no funciona Robinson.

Comment: por cierto. esas variables, fecha y hora de donde salen?. antes de asignarlas a fechaValidacion, tienen algun valor?

Comment: Si, son inputs de texto, lo que hago ahí es hacer una validación a la base de datos, cuando "fecha" que es el nombre del campo en la base de datos sea igual a "fecha" que es el input.

Comment: y por qué asignas fecha dentro de fechaValidacion dentro del forEach ?

Comment: Por que no sé dónde más puedo asignar el valor que me retorna...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123009/discussion-between-robinson-aguilar-and-daniel-rivas).

Comment: Lo mas probable es que los datos que comparas sean de diferente tipo. Desconozco que tipo de datos estas evaluando, pero es como si evaluases string de numeros contra numeros en si

Answer (score 1):

```
var fechaValidacion, horaValidacion;

db.collection("citas_registradas").where("fecha", "==", fecha).where("hora", "==", hora)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

                fechaValidacion = fecha;
                horaValidacion = hora;

            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        });
```

si las declaras asi serian globales, accesibles a todo el ambito
si quieres mantenerlas como privadas podrias meter la validacion dentro de una funcion y pasarle las variables como parametros

Comment: No amigo, ya probé ingresando la fecha "05/12/2021" y la hora "14:00" y aún me dice que la cita está disponible, cuando en realidad no está disponible ya que ya hay más de 15 citas llenas con esa fecha y hora :c

Comment: Puedes poner un console log en el foreach a ver que tipo de dato entrega?